# На минуточку (секундочку) обособляется (ли) как вводное?

Tags: вводные-слова

Народ на сайтах голосует "за", с народом не согласен словарь...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя проблемная ситуация:

> Невероятно талантливый человек, приятель Марселя Марсо и на секундочку
> ученик той самой Марии Осиповны Кнебель – он создавал настоящие "живые
> картины".

Допустимо ли тире (после "Кнебель") вместо положенной запятой? А то если обособим "на секундочку", об етии запятые глаз спотыкаться будет...

Поможите, люди добрыи, сами мы неместныи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Невероятно талантливый человек, приятель Марселя Марсо и, **на секундочку**, ученик той самой Марии Осиповны Кнебель – он создавал настоящие "живые картины".

1) На минуточку, на секундочку ― чаще обособляются. 2) А тире нужно, так как в препозиции находится **ряд приложений.**

Главный колокол, отлитый, между прочим, из двадцати восьми трофейных турецких пушек, весил, **на минуточку**, тысяча сто пятьдесят девять пудов. [Татьяна Соломатина. Мой одесский язык (2011)]

**На минуточку**, там гастарбайтеров чуть не вдвое, чем местных. [коллективный. Форум: Ливийская революция (2011)]

А это, **на минуточку**, основной ареал обитания нейтронов в тепловых реакторах! [коллективный. Форум: Торий (2008-2010)]

У Лопатина: При наличии ряда стоящих впереди определяемого слова однородных приложений: Современник Льва Толстого, Чехова и Горького, Н. Рериха и Рахманинова, страстный и даже пристрастный свидетель бурных революционных событий в России — Бунин нередко спорил с историей, с веком, с современниками (Л. Кр.).  [Знаки препинания при обособленных приложениях](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120)

Comment: Сиби, а не зап-тире? Категорически не?

Comment: У Лопатина только тире.

Comment: Пример с Буниным - не точная копия приведённой конструкции: *Невероятно талантливый человек, он...*, а внутри напиханы эти самые приложения, нет? Если нет, я покорно смирюсь.

Comment: Насколько я могу вспомнить,  ряд приложений может обособляться тире, что зависит от  определяемого слова (нариц,. собств, местоим. и  от желания автора придать ему обстоят. значение, как-то выделить). Вот еще пример: Замечательный художник, любитель устного народного творчества –  Виктор Васнецов создал целый цикл картин сказочной тематики. А тире и запятая ставятся в случае  однородных придаточных: Сколько было слёз, сколько радости,  – про всё не расскажешь. 
 
Что горько мне, что тяжко было и что внушало прибыль сил, с чем жизнь справляться торопила, –  я всё сюда и заносил.

Comment: Спасибо. Я думаю. Приходи исчо мне поотвечать... )))

Comment: Приду, попозже только, сегодня никак.